Difference in Difference with continuous treatment variable
I want to see the effect of conflict which causes fatalities in a region on the performance of financial institutions. I have data from 2015 to 2022 for 8 institutions operating in 8 counties. The fatalities-related data is the total fatalities caused by conflict till 2018 for each county which is a treatment variable. I want to apply DiD with a fixed effect before and after 2018. The model I specified is as follows:
$$
 Y_{it} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \text{Fatalities}_i + \beta_2\text{Post}_t + \beta_3\text{Fatalities}_i\text{Post}_t + X_{it} + \alpha_i + \gamma_t + \epsilon_{it}
$$
where $\alpha_i$ is the institution fixed effect and $\gamma_t$ is the time fixed effect.
Is the above model correct? What is the best way to carry out the analysis using DID with fixed effect?
​

Welcome. Can you tell us more about how you define $\text{Fatalities}_i$? I am a little confused when you say the total fatalities caused by conflict “till” 2018. What does this mean?

Thank you for the response. In fact, fatalities refer to total number of deaths caused by the conflict. The conflict period was from 2010 to 2018. I have data on total number of deaths for each county for the conflict period.
